# What can I do to increase my site's conversion rate?

Tags: usability, user-engagement, conversions, user-generated-content

I have a UGC site where I get some people from search. Most of them just leave, but I want to learn what to do to increase their conversion into community members.

Is there any free software available that helps with this?

Also, what can I track in the user session that might be helpful to get an understanding for how to get poeple to stay on the site.

Thanks!

Here is an example of a page that people land on so its more clean what I am talking about: http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=161

Answer (score 2):

These guys regularly put out great stuff on conversion rate optimization

http://www.conversion-rate-experts.com/learning-zone/

As for tools there are plenty of free or cheap options:

Free - Google analytics, google website optimizer, clicktale (has free and paid options) as well as survey type products kampyle, and 4q for example.

Affordable - usertesting.com, visual website optimizer, Get Clicky

Comment: thanks - some interesting resources for me to look at! Would you also have thoughts on why the page I linked to does not convert just by looking at it?

Comment: What works and what doesn't depends on your users, some things on the top of my head would be to test different layouts, sharing options and call to actions. It seems the first way to get people involved would be to get them to post a solution (assuming traffic from SE's is landing on internal pages) find ways to make that more visible. In terms of sharing let people post their problems to Facebook and recruit their friends for you. Etc. it's all about testing different things to see what works.